# Multiple Google maps, one map not Loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing a system in MVC 5 whereby a user can pick their coordinates from a google map and save them, the coordinates are stored to a database and then a separate page in the application retrieves the coordinates and displays the map with that Marker displayed.

My Problem is that while one map is functioning the other will not show up on a separate page.

Here is my Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    initialize();

});

function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('@ViewBag.Latitude', '@ViewBag.Longitude');

    var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.88484, -9.28484);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatLng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), mapOptions2);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: '@ViewBag.data'
    });

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map2,
        position: myLatLng2,
        draggable: true
    });

    new google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'drag', function () {
        var pos = marker2.getPosition();
        $("#Lat").val(pos.lat());
        $("#Lon").val(pos.lng());
    });


}
```

and in my First View

```
  <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left; width: 600px; height: 250px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:30px;">
```

and the Other View

```
<div id="map_canvas1" style="float:left; width: 600px; height: 250px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:30px;">
```

I can make "map2" work by commenting out the line

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);`

and vice versa but they will not seem to run along side each other,
only the first `var map` or `var map2` that is declared seems to run when both remain uncommented,
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Do the div's have closing tags `</div>`?

Comment: Oops! yea they do, just forgot to include them in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Is most likely erring out.  `map_canvas` doesn't exist, so the next line is never reached. If you comment it out, then the second view works as expected.

When calling `document.getElementById()`, make sure the element exists FIRST before creating a map.

BTW: That also means that `map_canvas1` does't exist on your first view either, so be careful there as well.

Try this:

```
var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
if (map_canvas)
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
var map_canvas1 = document.getElementById("map_canvas1");
if (map_canvas1)
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas1, mapOptions2);
```